# Using batch norm when restore the model?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have a little problem that using the batch norm when restore the model in tensorflow.

Below is my batch norm which from [here](https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html):

```py
def _batch_normalization(self, input_tensor, is_training, batch_norm_epsilon, decay=0.999):
    """batch normalization for dense nets.

    Args:
        input_tensor: `tensor`, the input tensor which needed normalized.
        is_training: `bool`, if true than update the mean/variance using moving average,
                             else using the store mean/variance.
        batch_norm_epsilon: `float`, param for batch normalization.
        decay: `float`, param for update move average, default is 0.999.

    Returns:
        normalized params.
    """
    # actually batch normalization is according to the channels dimension.
    input_shape_channels = int(input_tensor.get_shape()[-1])

    # scala and beta using in the the formula like that: scala * (x - E(x))/sqrt(var(x)) + beta
    scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([input_shape_channels]))
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_shape_channels]))

    # global mean and var are the mean and var that after moving averaged.
    global_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_shape_channels]), trainable=False)
    global_var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([input_shape_channels]), trainable=False)

    # if training, then update the mean and var, else using the trained mean/var directly.
    if is_training:
        # batch norm in the channel axis.
        axis = list(range(len(input_tensor.get_shape()) - 1))
        batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(input_tensor, axes=axis)

        # update the mean and var.
        train_mean = tf.assign(global_mean, global_mean * decay + batch_mean * (1 - decay))
        train_var = tf.assign(global_var, global_var * decay + batch_var * (1 - decay))
        with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
            return tf.nn.batch_normalization(input_tensor,
                                             batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, batch_norm_epsilon)
    else:
        return tf.nn.batch_normalization(input_tensor,
                                         global_mean, global_var, beta, scale, batch_norm_epsilon)
```

I train the model and save it using `tf.train.Saver()`. Below is the test code:

```py
def inference(self, images_for_predict):
    """load the pre-trained model and do the inference.

    Args:
        images_for_predict: `tensor`, images for predict using the pre-trained model.

    Returns:
        the predict labels.
    """

    tf.reset_default_graph()
    images, labels, _, _, prediction, accuracy, saver = self._build_graph(1, False)

    predictions = []
    correct = 0
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./models/dense_nets_model/dense_nets.ckpt.meta')
        # saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./models/dense_nets_model/'))
        saver.restore(sess, './models/dense_nets_model/dense_nets.ckpt')
        for i in range(100):
            pred, corr = sess.run([tf.argmax(prediction, 1), accuracy],
                                  feed_dict={
                                      images: [images_for_predict.images[i]],
                                      labels: [images_for_predict.labels[i]]})
            correct += corr
            predictions.append(pred[0])
    print("PREDICTIONS:", predictions)
    print("ACCURACY:", correct / 100)
```

But the predict result always very bad, like that:

```py
('PREDICTIONS:', [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

('ACCURACY:', 0.080000000000000002)
```

Some tips: `images_for_predict = mnist.test` and the `self._build_graph` method has two params: `batch_size` and `is_training`.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying a lot of methods, I solve this problem, below are what I did.

First thanks to @gdelab, I used `tf.layers.batch_normalization` instead, so my batch norm function like that:

```py
def _batch_normalization(self, input_tensor, is_training):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(input_tensor, training=is_training)
```

The param `is_training` is a placeholder like that: `is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)`

when building your graph, remember to add this code in your optimize:

```py
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

because the `tf.layers.batch_normalization` adds to update mean and variance don't automatically get added as dependencies of the train operation - so if you don't do anything extra, they never get run.

So begain to train the net, after finish the training, save the model using the code like that:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.global_variables())
savepath = saver.save(sess, 'here_is_your_personal_model_path')
```

Note that `var_list=tf.global_variables()` param make sure tensorflow save all the params include the global mean/var which are set not trainable.

when restore and test the model, do like that:

```py
# build the graph like training:
images, labels, _, _, prediction, accuracy, saver = self._build_graph(1, False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, 'here_is_your_personal_model_path')
```

And now one can test his/her model, hope that it can help u, thanks!

Comment: `var_list=tf.global_variables()` is not need,  `var_list` of `tf.train.Saver` defaults to the list of all saveable objects if None,

Answer (score 4):

Seeing your implementation of batch norm, when you load your model, you need to keep the graph built with `images, labels, _, _, prediction, accuracy, saver = self._build_graph(1, False)` and load the *weight values* for the chekpoint, but **NOT** the *meta graph*. I think that `saver.restore(sess, './models/dense_nets_model/dense_nets.ckpt')` also restores the meta graph now (sorry if I'm wrong), so you need to restore only the "data" part of it.

Otherwise, you're just using the graph for training, in which the mean and variance used in batch norm are the ones obtained from the batch. But when you're testing the batch has size 1, so normalizing by the mean and variance of the batch always brings your data to 0, hence the constant output.

In any case, I'd suggest using `tf.layers.batch_normalization` instead, with a `is_training` placeholder that you'll need to feed to your network...